# Google Place Picker Not Opening on One click in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile

I have used google place picker in android app for selecting location of the user by their wish. But when clicking the button it opened and suddenly it gets closed and if i click again only it opened to choose the location. And after opening also i can't search the location by typing the name.
Here i tried like this,

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Check Here"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Button button;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    location_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                        try {                           
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(PreviousAddressActivity.this),PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        });
}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("dataview", String.valueOf(data));
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                String longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                stringBuilder.append("LATITUDE :");
                stringBuilder.append(latitude);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                stringBuilder.append("Longitude");
                stringBuilder.append(longitude);

                Geocoder geocoder;
                List<Address> addresses;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Totally frustrated with this issue. Can anybody help me?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: hi sir @pankaj-kumar
Could you help me?

Comment: hi sir user:550966